# Can data be recovered after iOS system restore

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, restore, data-recovery

Is it possible to recover data from a restored iPhone. iPhone encrypts data by default so is there any chance of recovery after the key has been deleted during restore like brute force or jailbreaking etc?

Answer (score 1):

No. Once the key is deleted there is no way to recover the data. You could theoretically bruteforce the key, but this would take a very long time.